# ModBase64 NodeJS Crypto

Tags: node.js, cryptography, base64

I need to return a modBase64 encrypted value with nodejs crypto, as the java implementation is made so

> The output will be modified Base64.
>       Modified Base64 for URLs replaces the '+' and '/' characters
>       of standard Base64 with '-' and '_' respectively, so that these
>       Base64 signatures no longer need to be URL-encoded.

is there a way to return that format?

Comment: Yes. Find that base64 function in nodejs documentation then [`replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) '+' and '/' with '-' and '_'

Comment: yes, but I meant, any solution from the crypto library